# Dynamically change "Merge and Center" column name from drop-down and get data according to column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, header, lookup, export-to-excel

Here ListA and ListB are main headers there will be more So I should be able to create a drop down of main headers ListA and ListB and so on. ON whichever cell I want to add the data I will selective the header name and respective header data should appear.

So I want to dynamically switch between the headers via dropdown in one specific cell and the data of respective header should populate once I add it in Dropdown.

Comment: So what's your data? (you could share dummy data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables); what's your own attempt? What did it output? what did you expect it to output? Please edit your question to mention this.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637145/dynamically-change-merge-and-center-column-name-and-get-data-according-to-colu ? Please edit the question rather than opening a new one.